# How to copy Angular dist content to another location after generating the build?

Tags: angular, build, copy

After generating the build using ng build how can I automatically copy the files from dist folder to another location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update the package.json file to add

```
"postbuild":"xcopy /s \".\/dist\" \"my\\folder\\path\" \/Y",
```

in the scripts object, replace the **my/folder/path** with your destination path.

**/Y will not ask in the prompt to overwrite files.**

Now run

```
npm run build
```

After the build the content of the dist will be copied to the folder.

Comment: you also can combine that: `"build": "ng build && npm run postbuild"`

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull didn't worked for me when I ran ng build. I am using npm run build for doing it.

Comment: ng build does not run the npm script. If you want the combined you have to run `npm run build`

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull without combining the commands it is working fine so need to combine. I had tried to combine the commands but it didn't worked.

Comment: Note: If the target directory does not exist you can use the xcopy `/I` option to create it without prompting.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you change the value of outputPath in angular.json. 
Note: This is path where angular puts build artifacts. You will no longer see dist/yourProjectName to have been updated as the artifacts directly go to your given path.
Below is excerpt of angular.json

```
 "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../../../../BackEnd/NodeJs/hostAngularProjectOnNodeJS/AppBackend/public/angular",
```

Comment: This can also be done and depends on the requirement.